# CMake unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a very simple CMake project using Visual Studio 2013, however I am getting the following error upon trying to compile it:

```cpp
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   cmake_issue\build\Debug\cmake_issue.exe 1   1   cmake_issue
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int Other::value" (?value@Other@@2HA) cmake_issue\build\test.obj  cmake_issue
```

I have a base directory with the following `CMakeLists.txt` in:

```
project(cmake_issue)
add_subdirectory(other)
add_executable(cmake_issue src/test.cc)
target_link_libraries(cmake_issue other)
```

And the contents of `src/test.cc`:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

#include "other/other.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("value = %d\n", Other::value);

    return 0;
}
```

And a subdirectory called `other` with the following `CMakeLists.txt` in:

```
add_library(other SHARED src/other.cc)
target_include_directories(other PUBLIC include)
target_link_libraries(other)
```

And the contents of `other/include/other/other.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef _OTHER_H_
#define _OTHER_H_

class __declspec(dllexport) Other {
public:
    static int value;
};

#endif
```

And the contents of `other/src/other.cc`:

```cpp
#include "other/other.h"

int Other::value = 30;
```

If I build the project with cmake and then open the generated sln in Visual Studio, both of the projects appear in the Solution Explorer.

If I right click and build `other`, it builds fine. However if I try and build `cmake_issue`, I get the errors above. It looks like the `cmake_issue` solution is not using the `other.dll` (or `other.lib`) files being generated when compiling the `other` solution.

I can upload a zip of the source if it is needed.

Comment: The code seems ok, except this empty link directive: `target_link_libraries(other)`. Could you, please, upload a zip?

Comment: [Here is a zip of the project](https://mega.nz/#!TBcGkLjQ!ANS2580AlvWLXgmp_1G26MF8RCmqtujJlkP9ecajEPQ). The odd thing is that it compiles on Linux using GNU Make (I have to remove the `__declspec(dllexport)` through, as it's an unexpected token), which makes me believe it's an issue with VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the problem is not on CMake side, but with C++. When you used dllexport'ed class in your executable, its definintion should read `class __declspec(dllimport) Other`. This code works fine, for example:

```
#include <cstdio>

class __declspec(dllimport) Other {
public:
    static int value;
    int a();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("value = %d\n", Other::value);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a link with complete solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c43599d-6d9d-4709-abf5-4d1e3f5e4fc9/exporting-static-class-members